# How Can I Access Webpack Modules Using a "Short" Path (Like "Global Require" For Babel/NPM)

Tags: webpack

**TLDR**

Is there a plug-in for Webpack that let's your bring in the module `foo/bar/baz` using only `require('baz')`?

**FULL**

I just came across an interesting plug-in for Babel/NPM:

https://github.com/CentaurWarchief/babel-plugin-global-require

This plug-in let's you require your NPM modules using only the most-specific part of the module's path.  For instance, if your filesystem has:

```
src
  util
    foo
      Bar.js
```

instead of doing:

```
require('src/util/foo/Bar');
```

you can just do:

```
require('Bar');
```

If (for instance) you happen to have two "Bar.js" files, you can instead do:

```
require('foo/bar');
```

That's awesome ... if you use NPM as your module system.  But I'm looking to switch to using Webpack, so my question is: does anything like I just described exist as a Webpack plug-in?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Webpack has similar feature built in. Add paths to your modules to [resolve.root](http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#resolve-root) array in your webpack config file.

```
resolve: {
    root: [path.join(__dirname, 'src/util/foo')]
}
```

and then `require('Bar');`

In that case that there is multiple files with same name you have to add their common parent folder to `resolve.root` array.

Folder structure:

```
src
  util
    foo
      Bar.js
    bar
      Bar.js
```

Webpack config:

```
resolve: {
    root: [path.join(__dirname, 'src/util')]
}
```

and then

```
require('foo/Bar');
require('bar/Bar');
```

**EDIT**

Use absolute paths. Thanks ErikPhipps for comment.

Comment: Perfect, that was exactly what I was looking for, thanks!

Comment: The documentation mentions that the path must be absolute: "It must be an absolute path! Don’t pass something like ./app/modules."